# GDPR: what can I record about website visitors?

Tags: european-union, gdpr, website

My use case is very simple. I have a website, on which I have articles that I wrote. It behooves me to learn about the people who visit my site so that I know what articles are popular and why, mainly. I want to record the following:

1. time/date of visit
2. what browser they used, and what OS
3. what their ISP is (or other type of host), which seems hard to determine so usually I don't have this info.
4. what webpage they visited.

Noticed I do not record:

- IP address
- GPS coordinates (no drone strike possible)
- any username or password
- the person's name, because I don't know it

And there are no cookies.

Does the GDPR allow this limited recording?

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to record what you are about to, and even feel free to add IP addresses and GPS coordinates without even letting visitors know. You have these 2 defenses:

1. You are not offering goods or services to your visitors (like if
   you were charging subscription fees to access your articles),
   therefore your site falls under [Recital 18 — Not applicable to
   personal or household activities](https://gdpr-info.eu/recitals/no-18/);
2. You are not able to identify the real persons behind the data you record at reasonable time and costs, therefore it is not personal data ([Recital 26 — Not applicable to anonymous data](https://gdpr-info.eu/recitals/no-26/)).

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to record the personal data you mention (in general the GDPR does limit your ability to record personal data - the GDPR only tell you what you must do *if* you collect personal data.  I.e. you don't *need* any "defenses" in order to legally do this.

However, I do not think you are *exempt* from the GDPR if you collect the personal data you list about the people who visit your website.

Whether a personal website is covered by "personal use exemption" or whether a IP-address is personal data is currently contested in answers to other questions on Law stack exchange. See, for instance [Are server-logs reckoned as storing of personal data by website?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/28668/957).

I think you should read the linked, and related, Q&As, and the make up your own mind about whether you have to comply with the GDPR if you record this personal data.