# Explanations for GDPR if no personal data is collected?

Tags: gdpr, data-protection

I have a website that is a travel search engine and I am very concerned about GDPR.

I am not interested in any private information from the users for marketing or such things. I just use Google Analytics to see the behavior on the page and to be able to improve it. No log-ins or accounts, no retargetting, no e-mail gathering, no newsletters...

According to [GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-4-gdpr/):

> ‘personal data’ means any information relating to an identified or
>   identifiable natural person (‘data subject’); an identifiable natural
>   person is one who can be identified, directly or indirectly, in
>   particular by reference to an identifier such as a name, an
>   identification number, location data, an online identifier or to one
>   or more factors specific to the physical, physiological, genetic,
>   mental, economic, cultural or social identity of that natural person;

I have already [anonymized the IPs for Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2763052?hl=en), so I would assume I do not have any personal data from the users anymore.

Is my assumption correct?

If so, do I need to care about all the clear explanations like where data is stored, how long is stored and so? Or can I just say something like:

> "This website does not collect any personal data"

?

Comment: Does your webserver [log](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/28609/18215) it's requests?

Comment: If you do not process any personal data, the GDPR does not apply to you. In that case you do not even need add a note, but it won't hurt either.

Comment: It might anonymize the IP (xxx.xxx.xxx.0) and store it for maximum one day. After that, the anonymized IP is deleted.

Comment: @wimh: "In that case you do not even need add a note" - do you have a citation for that? It would seem somewhat logical, but I feel I have read a large number of articles about the topic, and providing a privacy policy was treated as seemingly mandatory absolutely everywhere. Not a single time did I see a site mention the possibility that a website does not need a GDPR-compliant privacy policy. Aside from that, the idea that "but it won't hurt either" *might* be a bit careless. *If* "no privacy note" is a legal solution, having one might unnecessarily open an attack vector based upon ...

Comment: ... formal mistakes in the privacy note text.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Article 2 defines the scope of the GDPR. If you don't process any personal data, the GDPR does not apply based on that. However I am not sure whether a webserver really does not process any personal data, the requests an replies include an ip adress. Processing as defined in the GDPR includes any kind of operation, even deleting...